# Rewrite Rule not working on 1and1 server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

After 4 hours of thinking i'm stupid i checked it on another hoster and it works. But it does not work on a 1and1 server.

There are to ways that route to style.css

This one routes style.1234567.css:

RewriteRule ^(.+).(\d+).(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]

and this one style-fb1234567.css:

RewriteRule (.*)-fb\d+.(.*)$ $1.$2 [L]

but just on this server it does not. All the other rewrites in my htaccess work. I also toke them out to see if another rule does stop this two from working. But thats not the case. So what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteRule (.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
RewriteRule (.+)-fb\d+\.(.+)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

Comment: Ok, after days waiting for the 1and1 support they told me that they have Apache 1.3 running and this rule does not work there the way it's written.